# Character missing when saving a row?

Tags: php, zend-framework, character-encoding, zend-db, multibyte

```
$userTb = new My_Tb_User();  //Child of Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
$row = $userTb->find(9)->current();
$row->name = 'STÖVER';
$row->save();
```

Inside user table at row 9 for name column value `ST` gets stored instead of `STÖVER` ?

`Ö` is a german character supported in `UTF-8` . IF I enter manually 'STÖVER' using phpmyadmin it get stored correctly .

I also passed charset parameter with value `utf8` when creating db adapter but still no luck !

Comment: just send your text data as UTF-8 too

Comment: Just a guess: what if you try: `$row->name = utf8_encode('STÖVER');`

Comment: ALTER DATABASE mydatabasename charset=utf8;

Comment: use       mysql_real_escape_string()     at the time of inserting into db

Comment: @Ninsuo your guess solved my problem but I would like to know why ?

Comment: @soul its already in utf-8 also its not database charset problem otherwise entering the value through phpmyadmin would have not worked correctly .

Comment: @Daya that didn't work .

Comment: The PHP default encoding is latin1 (iso8859-1), you need to set it to utf8 in your php.ini file, `default_charset = "UTF-8"`. Else, your php file will not be read as utf-8.

Comment: @Ninsuo  setting `ini_set('default_charset',"UTF-8")` and removing utf8_encode() did not work as I again got ST saved in database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bad practice to use `utf8_encode`, this adds a lot of complexity to your app. Try to solve the problem by looking for the source.

Ssome thoughts :

- a database server charset problem (check encoding of your server)
- a database client charset problem (check encoding of your connection)
- a database table charset problem (check encoding of your table)
- a php default encoding problem (check `default_encoding` parameter in parameters.ini)
- a multibyte missconfigured (see mb_string parameters in parameters.ini)
- a `<form>` charset problem (check that it is sent as utf-8)
- a `<html>` charset problem (where no enctype is set in your html file)
- a `Content-encoding:` problem (where the wrong encoding is sent by Apache).

Comment: PHP doesn't "read files as" a certain encoding. It reads them as binary blob and doesn't care about encodings.

Comment: You're right, I read again manual, this parameter only modifies the `Content-type` header. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

If you read the manual entry for [`utf8_encode`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700275/utf8-encode-function-purpose), it *converts an ISO-8859-1 encoded string to UTF-8*. The function name is a horrible misnomer, as it suggests some sort of automagic encoding that is necessary. That is not the case. If your source code is saved as UTF-8 and you assign "STÖVER" to `$string`, then `$string` holds the character "STÖVER" encoded in UTF-8. No further action is necessary. In fact, trying to convert the UTF-8 string (incorrectly) from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 will garble it.

```
utf8_encode('STÖVER');
```

check this question in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700275/utf8-encode-function-purpose)

Comment: Good quote there. Not sure what it has to do with the question though.